# Can I fix Reallocated Sectors Count and Current Pending Sector Count?

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, hardware-failure, bad-sectors

I have problem(Caution) with Reallocated Sectors Count and Current Pending Sector Count. I detected this problem after running CrystalDiskInfo, knowing that Iam using hp laptop running windows10. Any suggestion to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure your backup is current & test it can be successfully used for recovery.
2. Buy a new drive.
3. Make use of 1.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot really "fix" these numbers as they represent the degraded state of your HDD/SSD.

Here's what you should do:

- Regularly check if these numbers are growing or not. If they aren't, you're OK and there's no need to worry.
- If these numbers are growing fast, it's time to replace your disk.

**Lastly and most importantly**:

- **Make backups** regularly if you care about your data - this is regardless of SMART values and everything that I've written above.